# Is there a way to get SharpDevelop program to always stay on top other windows?

Tags: c#, windows-media-player, sharpdevelop

I am working in SharpDevelop C#, and I am wondering if there is a way to always keep the program to stay on top of every other window. I am following a tutorial to learn C# but it is getting annoying switching between Media Player and SharpDevelop program.  It's not that big of a deal, I know, but just wondering if there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: What kind of program, console, windows forms, wpf?

Comment: I don't completely understand your question.  The program is called SharpDevelop and it is an IDE am using for C#. SharpDevelop is a code editor (Visual Studio/Xamarin alternative).

Comment: I thought you meant the program you're trying to develop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are tools to have media player (and 99% of any app) staying on top. 
Because I won't recommend one please search "Always On Top" or  "Window on top"

If you want to write your own, you need to find get window handle of the top-level window of that application, then do something like (w is the HWND). Sample code in c++:

```
  HWND w=GetForegroundWindow(); // or  w=WindowFromPoint(cursorpos);

  DWORD isTop=GetWindowLong(w, GWL_EXSTYLE)&WS_EX_TOPMOST;

  SetWindowPos(w, isTop ? HWND_NOTOPMOST : HWND_TOPMOST, 0,0,0,0, SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOACTIVATE|SWP_NOSIZE);
```

In C# you need P/Invoke.

Comment: Thank you.  I downloaded Turbo Top and I got it working now.